# Select-string escape character

Tags: powershell, escaping, character, unc, select-string

I'm trying to search directory `c:\bats\` for batch files containing the unc path `\\server\public`

Command:

```
Get-ChildItem -path c:\bats\ -recurse | Select-string -pattern "\\server\public"
```

I receive an error related to the string `\\server\public`:

```
Select-string : The string \\server\public is not a valid regular
expression: parsing "\\server\public" - Malformed \p{X} character
escape. At line:1 char:91
+ ... ts" -recurse | Select-string -pattern \\server\public
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegex,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

I've tried using various escapes such as `"\server\public"` or `"'\server\public'"` but I always receive that same error.

Answer (score 8):

To expand more on the problem since the solution is in @campbell.rw's answer. The `Select-String` parameter `-Pattern` supports regular expressions. The backslash is a control character and needs to be escaped. It is not that you need to escape it from PowerShell but the regex engine itself. The escape character is also a backslash

```
Select-string -pattern '\\\\server\\public'
```

You can use a static method from the regex class to do that hard work for you.

```
Select-string -pattern ([regex]::Escape('\\server\public'))
```

Again, in your case, using the `-SimpleMatch` is a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try this using single quotes around your search string and specifying SimpleMatch.

```
Get-ChildItem -path c:\bats\ -recurse | Select-string -pattern '\\server\public' -SimpleMatch
```

Comment: what if the pattern is in variable ?

Comment: @ShreedharDhanawade I don't know about your situation but I found that my issue was that I was accidentally using a variable that was an array for the match. I narrowed to a string and that solved the problem.